# How to stream data using promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, streaming

How can I stream data using promises.

I have two different functions in two different files. In one calls an API service and that returns a promise.

```
  async myPromise(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      callToAnAPI().then(()=>{
          resolve ("pending");
      }).then(()=>{
        resolve(callToAnotherAPI());
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          // error handling
      });
    });
  }
```

In another file I have a function like so:

```
  async myPromise2(){
    functionFromOtherFile().then((data)=>{
        // how can I get 'pending' here?
    }).then(data =>{
        // how can I get data fromncallToAnotherAPI() here?
    })
  }
```

I want to know that the api has been called and that it is in 'pending' state. How can I achieve this?

Comment: A promise represents a single future value, you cannot "stream" with them. You are likely looking for observables, e.g. https://rxjs.dev/.

Comment: How can I turn an api call to an observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream is just an async iterator... So we could just use callback, much like node.js

```js
function myPromise(cl) {
    cl(null, "pending")
    setTimeout(() => {
        cl(null, "data")
    }, 2000);
}

function myPromise2() {
    myPromise((err, data) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
}

myPromise2()
```

Answer (score 1):

The most elegant way in my opinion is to return two promises and process them separately.

```js
  function myPromise(){
    const api1Status = callToAnAPI().then(()=>{
        resolve ("pending");
    });
    return [
      api1status,
      api1status.then(()=>{
        resolve(callToAnotherAPI());
      })
      .catch(err=>{
          // error handling
      })
    ];
  }
```

Then the second file would use it like this:

```js
  async myPromise2(){
    const [api1, api2] = functionFromOtherFile();
    const shouldSayPending = await api1;
    const shoudHaveData = await api2;
  }
```

The first function doesn't need to be an async one then, you just return a number of promises.

You could also consider async generators, which would give you a nicer code in the first method, but less nice in the second, like this:

```js
async function* myPromise() {
    try {
        yield await callToAnApi(); // we need to await here so that 
        yield callToAnotherApi();  // this method is executed after.
    } catch(e) {
        // error handling
    }

}
```

The other side would result in something like this:

```js
async myPromise2() {
    const progress = theIteratorFromOtherFile(); // just call the function*

    const shouldBePending = (await progress.next()).value;
    const theOtherResult = (await progress.next()).value;
}
```

Performance wise there's very little difference between the two - you're doing async operations so these are your bottlenecks. The choice is then up to your personal preference.